# Visual studio stuck cursor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In unity and visual studio , some of the scripts I am creating ,wont let me use shortcuts, cant write where I put the cursor, cant even use ctrl+F, this is new and really stopping my workflow. Have you got any workarounds for this bug?

When I type it seems like the place where all the words are typed from it is always the same and won't change no matter if I click on a different place in the script.

If I restart visual studio, the problem for those scripts will stop, but other scripts will have the same problem then.

I am using visual studio 17 15.9 and Unity 2018.3.b10

Thank you for your help

Comment: 15.9.3 seems to fix some issues with VS and unity. Do you already use 15.9.3? See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/387541/issues-with-project-reloading-and-intellisense-wit.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#-visual-studio-2017-version-1593-

Comment: thank you yes installed it this morning and the same problem  is there, I wonder if I am the only one...

Comment: Did you also try to restart Unity not only VS? In some cases remove all files and folders except `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` and let Unity rebuild the solution on the next start

Comment: yes, I keep restarting and that problem persists. I think It must be related to visual studio mainly

Comment: just edited my comment hehe ;) try to close Unity, delete those folders and files especially `.vs` and anything ending with `.sln` and `.csproj`. Then open Unity and let it recompile

Comment: It is such a weird bug that may end up using an older version of visual studio. Although It seems complicated to use an old version as I need to select the .net core and I dont know which one to use...

Comment: @derHugo I am going to try that and see, and I will also delete the library folder...

Comment: There should be no problem to go for `.Net4.6.` but do it within Unity in the Player settings

Comment: when you say to do it within unity in the player settings you mean to select the .net but also visual studio asks me to select the .net core when installing lets see If I can manage to install that old version

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a workaround. My scripts in visual studio were coming up on the tabs with a 1 or 2 after the name of the script, like they were duplicates. The solution was to close them pressing x, then find them in the solution explorer, repeating this until that number was gone.
After this, that problem is gone.